# How do I fix "No ESLint configuration found" for files outside the folder with .eslintrc.js? (takes place only when I try to use a enum value)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

### The app structure

I'm creating a fullstack app (Node.js + TypeScript + Vue, other bits are irrelevant) and I have the following folder structure:

```
<project root>
  model/
  front/
    src/
    node_modules/
    package.json
    .eslintrc.js     // note where it is
    ...
  back/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  ...
```

Since `front/` was based on the app created with `vue-cli` and I like having `node_modules` of frontend separate from those of backend, the structure of `front/` is standart for a vue app.

### The common model (for front and back)

I have TS model common for front and back and it is stored in

```
model/
  objects.ts
  api.ts
```

To use `api.ts` in the frontend part, I have `front/src/store/api.ts` which reads as just

```
// re-export from fullstack common model
export * from '../../../model/api'
```

That worked fine with interfaces defined in `model/api.ts` (and `model/objects.ts`), for instance I can use

```
import { TestApiResponse } from '../api'
...
const testUser: TestApiResponse = response.data;
```

in `front/src/store/modules/user.ts`.

### The problem

I've tried to also introduce

```
export enum Endpoints {
  TestApi = 'testApi',
}
```

to use it in both front and back, like the interfaces, the whole minimal api.ts looks like

```
import { UserBase } from './objects'

export enum Endpoints {
  TestApi = 'testApi',
}

export interface TestApiResponse extends UserBase {}
```

That by itself doesn't break anything. I can also write

```
import { Endpoints, TestApiResponse } from '../api'
```

in `user.ts` and the project still compiles (both `npm run serve` and `npm run build` work without errors).

But once I also substitute (in `user.ts`)

```
const response = await axios.get(Vue.prototype.$apiRoot + 'testApi');
```

with

```
const response = await axios.get(Vue.prototype.$apiRoot + Endpoints.TestApi);
```

both dev server (`npm run serve`) and `npm run build` start to show

```
Failed to compile.

../model/api.ts Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: No ESLint configuration found in <project root>\model.
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._finalizeConfigArray (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:432:19)
at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:271:21)
at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:951:18)
at CLIEngine.executeOnText (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:868:38)
at lint (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:278:17) at transform (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:252:18)
at <project root>\front\node_modules\loader-fs-cache\index.js:127:18 at ReadFileContext.callback (<project root>\front\node_modules\loader-fs-cache\index.js:31:14)
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:273:13)
```

The main difference is that I use enum *values* unlike just *types* before (adding `let e: Endpoints;` doesn't produce an error). The other bit that most likely contributes to the problem: `<project root>/model/api.ts` is outside `<project root>/front/` which contains `.eslintrc.js` (using values of a `enum` from, say, `front/src/router/index.ts` doesn't produce errors). **Any ideas why is this so and/or how can I fix this?**

(I've tried to just copy `.eslintrc.js` to the root folder or to `model/` but that haven't fixed the issue)

PS here's `.eslintrc.js` generated by vue cli:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

PPS Well, I've tried to move `.eslintrc.js` to the root folder, but in this case `npm run serve` shows

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: Failed to load config "@vue/typescript/recommended" to extend from.
Referenced from: <project root>\.eslintrc.js
    at configMissingError (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:265:9)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtendedShareableConfig (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:826:23)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtends (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:731:25)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigDataBody (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:660:25)
    at _normalizeObjectConfigDataBody.next (<anonymous>)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigData (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:596:20)
    at _normalizeObjectConfigData.next (<anonymous>)
    at createConfigArray (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:340:25)
    at ConfigArrayFactory.loadInDirectory (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\config-array-factory.js:433:16)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:328:46)      
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:347:20)      
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:347:20)      
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:347:20)      
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:347:20)      
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cascading-config-array-factory.js:272:18)       
    at CLIEngine.isPathIgnored (<project root>\front\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine\cli-engine.js:951:18)
```

Moreover, if I copy (instead of moving) `.eslintrc.js` to the root folder, I see the same errors (after restarting `npm run serve`). I guess, I have to install something into the root package.json, but I'm not sure what exactly (`front/node_modules/@vue/` doesn't contain `typescript/recommended`). In if I remove the `, '@vue/typescript/recommended'` bit from `.eslintrc` in the root, I get

```
<project root>\model\api.ts
  4:8  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token enum
```

hmm.. presumably I have to configure eslint to work with TS from scratch at this point... I've tried to follow some bits from [here](https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/eslint-for-typescript/):

1. `npm i -D eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`
2. added to .eslintrc `plugins: [ '@typescript-eslint' ],` and to `extends` there `'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'`

but got `Unexpected token enum` again. Not sure how to sort this out.

Perhaps it's not a good idea to setup eslint via vue cli in a fullstack project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, maybe the plugin you're looking for is called **@vue/eslint-config-typescript** - at least installing it helped me (although I had to pick up a version that was compatible with other dependencies).

But it's not just about the plugin, it's about the fact that ESLint follows the principle of [Сascading and Hierarchy](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#cascading-and-hierarchy):

> There are two ways to use configuration files.
>
> The first way to use configuration files is via `.eslintrc.*` and
> `package.json` files. ESLint automatically looks for them in the
> directory of the file to be linted, and in successive parent
> directories all the way up to the root directory of the filesystem (`/`)
> [...]

So all you have to do is move your **.eslintrc.js** from the `front` folder to the `<project root>` folder, like this:

```
<project root>
  .eslintrc.js // works for all subdirectories, incl. "model/"
  model/
  front/
    src/
    node_modules/
    package.json
  back/
  node_modules/
  package.json
```